# Excel Userform VBA won't move to next row

Tags: vba, excel

My userform works fine to fill in the fields on an excel spreadsheet, but it refuses to move to the next line. I can't do it by asking to find an empty row either, because columns A and C are prefilled. Is there a way to make the userform jump to the next line once it has been complete and submitted and the fields are filled out, maybe by using the B column as a way to know whether the row is open to use? Because no matter what, the A and C columns are filled. Also, once the user is done, saves the document, and comes back to it later, will the userform pick up on whatever line it last left off on? I know i posted this already, but no solutions have worked and I figured I would add more detail. Sorry if some of this seems novice, I am new to VBA. Thank you!

```
Private Sub butOK_Click()
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ctl As Control

RowCount = Worksheets("EXPECTED RETURNS").Range("A6865").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
 With Worksheets("EXPECTED RETURNS").Range("A6865")
.Offset(LastRow, 1).Value = Me.txtDate.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 3).Value = Me.txtDevice.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 4).Value = Me.txtID.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 5).Value = Me.txtSN.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 6).Value = Me.txtTrans.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 7).Value = Me.txtIDTrans.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 8).Value = Me.txtMS.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 9).Value = Me.txtCountry.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 10).Value = Me.txtCamp.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 11).Value = Me.txtOrig.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 12).Value = Me.txtProgram.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 13).Value = Me.txtPOC.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 14).Value = Me.txtPOCEmail.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 15).Value = Me.txtDSN.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 16).Value = Me.txtIR.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 17).Value = Me.txtEI.Value
End With

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
ctl.Value = ""
ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
ctl.Value = False
End If
Next ctl

End Sub
```

Comment: `LastRow` or `RowCount`?

Comment: I don't see where you set the `LastRow` variable, so it's just `0`. Therefore your `offset()` is moving down 0 rows and adding new data. Which, of course, is always going to be row "A6865". Perhaps change `RowCount = ` to `LastRow = ` and rerun.

Comment: I tried, but now nothing happens. How do I better define it?

Comment: I would think you'd use `.Offset(LastRow+1` to put the data in the next row below the last one. Then, if you're looping, just `LastRow=LastRow+1` before the loop starts again and you should be good.

Comment: Although, if `Range("A6865")` is not part of the same region as `Range("A1")`, it's possible that `RowCount` does not hold the expected value, either.

Comment: Please provide the full code that includes the `LastRow` variable. As of now, we are just speculating that you have the variables set.

Comment: I added the full code, nothing mentioned so far has worked

Comment: Where is your setting for `LastRow`?

Comment: I guess I don't have one, how do I do that?

Comment: As has been pointed out - you haven't defined which row number `LastRow` is meant to be.  You say you can use column B to find the last row so use `LastRow = Worksheets("Expected Returns").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` to find the last populated row - add 1 to get the next available row.

Comment: What if every row is populated, the first and third columns are all filled going all the way down and always are filled?

Comment: If you want to find the last row using column A or column C then change the `Cells(Rows.Count,2)` to `Cells(Rows.Count,1)` for A and `Cells(Rows.Count,3)` for C - it will then take that as the last row.  If _every row_ is populated how do you want to decide which row to add the data to?

Comment: I tried, this makes it not put anything into the sheet at all :/ and a typo, I didn't mean every I meant just the two columns are filled the rest are empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will find the last used row in `EXPECTED RETURNS` sheet and copy data in next row. Also, it assumes that you set a `tag` number to all your relevant elements in the form: 1 for `TextDate`, 3 for `TextDevice` and so on. This way, your code can be reduce to something like the following:

```
Private Sub butOK_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim i As Integer

    'Get last row with data
    LastRow = Worksheets("EXPECTED RETURNS").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Get all control values, and write to column according to their tag
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.Tag <> "" Then
            i = ctl.Tag
            Worksheets("EXPECTED RETURNS").Cells(LastRow, i) = ctl.Value
        End If
    Next

    'Clear all controls
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
            ctl.Value = ""
        ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
            ctl.Value = False
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

Comment: how do I set a tag for each element? (in this case text box)

Comment: Right click on the element (textbox, checkbox, etc) --> Properies. Then type a number in the Tag property.

Comment: Can you provide more info of what is wrong? Above code is working for me...

Comment: It just doesn't add anything to the sheet at all, compared to before where it would at least just put it in the same row.

Comment: Press F8 to step into the code. Pressing F8 you will go step by step. Hovering the mouse over the variables you are able to see their value.

Comment: sorry to be a newbie, but can you explain "write to column according to their tag"?

Comment: Take a close look at the code. For each control (textbox, checkbox, etc) the code gets its tag number and store it in variable i (`i=ctl.Tag`). Then, in row `LastRow` and column `i`, the code writes the control value. So, if you set Tag=3 for `txtDevice`, the code will write the value of `txtDevice` in column 3.

Comment: ok, makes sense. thank you! do I write it in brackets or the quotes?

Comment: The above code, in its present form,  works fine for me.

Comment: @Jamie its hard to say what is wrong just by "still doesn't work for me". We're blind, since its working for me. Did you try to go step by step pressing F8? Did you check the values of the variables, hovering the mouse over them?

Comment: yeah, it runs fine and then empties the form when complete, but there is nothing to show in the sheet itself. It just doesn't fill in.

Comment: Did you add a tag value to the TextBoxs? You could check this with F8, and holding the mouse over `i`.

Comment: @Jamie In the line `LastRow = Worksheets("EXPECTED RETURNS").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`, try changing "A" to "B". Since column B is one that you are filling in, and column A is pre-filled, you should try to get the last used row from column B instead of A.

Comment: Try inserting `MsgBox ("Starting")` after `Dim i As Integer`, `MsgBox ("LR: " & LastRow)` after `LasRow=....`, and `MsgBox ("Tag: " & i & " Value: " & ctl.Value)` after `i = ctl.Tag`. After clicking `butOK` you should see alerts that may help you to find the error.

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead...

```
last = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YOURSHEET").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Yourshee").Cells(last + 1, 1) = anything()                          'data
    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Yoursheet").Cells(last + 1, 2) = anything            
    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Yoursheet").Cells(last + 1, 3) = anything
    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Yoursheet").Cells(last + 1, 4) = anything            
    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Yoursheet").Cells(last + 1, 5) = anything 
    MsgBox "Sucess"
```

You can add na iff statement to have a positive result and a negative result if you want

Comment: This code makes no sense, where does the `else` or `end if` come from ? Why would you hide the UserForm?

Comment: I Forget to delete that part. Sorry