# Userform won't move to next line

Tags: vba, excel

My userform works fine to fill in the fields on an excel spreadsheet, but it refuses to move to the next line. I can't do it by asking to find an empty row either, because columns A and C are prefilled. Is there a way to make the userform jump to the next line once it has been complete and submitted and the fields are filled out, maybe by using the B column as a way to know whether the row is open to use? Because no matter what, the A and C columns are filled. 
Also, once the user is done, saves the document, and comes back to it later, will the userform pick up on whatever line it last left off on? I know i posted this already, but no solutions have worked and I figured I would add more detail. Sorry if some of this seems novice, I am new to VBA. Thank you!

```
Private Sub butOK_Click()


Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ctl As Control

RowCount = Worksheets("EXPECTED RETURNS").Range("A6865").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("EXPECTED RETURNS").Range("A6865")
.Offset(LastRow, 1).Value = Me.txtDate.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 3).Value = Me.txtDevice.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 4).Value = Me.txtID.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 5).Value = Me.txtSN.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 6).Value = Me.txtTrans.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 7).Value = Me.txtIDTrans.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 8).Value = Me.txtMS.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 9).Value = Me.txtCountry.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 10).Value = Me.txtCamp.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 11).Value = Me.txtOrig.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 12).Value = Me.txtProgram.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 13).Value = Me.txtPOC.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 14).Value = Me.txtPOCEmail.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 15).Value = Me.txtDSN.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 16).Value = Me.txtIR.Value
.Offset(LastRow, 17).Value = Me.txtEI.Value
End With



For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
ctl.Value = ""
ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
ctl.Value = False
End If
Next ctl

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean "refuses to move to the next line"? What is `LastRow`?

Comment: after hitting ok, if I fill the userform out again it will just replace what was put into the current line

Comment: @Jamie you asked the same question [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50607751/1726522), but did not pay attention to the comments. First of all, `LastRow` is not defined!!

Comment: I agree with SJR that the code you posted is too incomplete, since the `LastRow` variable is not defined in it. However, the problem is probably the way you're using the `Offset` function, since it doesn't make much sense, semantically at least, to offset by the row number of the last row. Please read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Userform VBA won't move to next row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607751/excel-userform-vba-wont-move-to-next-row).  As @CMArg said.  Edit your original question if people aren't understanding - asking again will just get the same people seeing it and asking the same questions, or ignoring it completely.

Comment: Please don't re-post a question when you've already had an answer. It wastes everybody's time. Work through the problems you have on that question.

Comment: When I define LastRow, it stops working. It won't then place anything into the spreadsheet.

Comment: my apologies, I will edit the original question.